# Jooq column name case insensitive

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I am working on a jooq project ,

Is there any way we can make column names and table names case insensitive and quote insensitive queries in jooq.

If column names are in quoted Upper case ,If I query with quoted lower case column names I am getting error . Same with table name as well

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [`Settings.renderQuotedNames`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dsl-context/custom-settings/settings-name-style/) setting, e.g.

```java
settings.setRenderQuotedNames(RenderQuotedNames.EXPLICIT_DEFAULT_UNQUOTED)
```

This will remove the quoting from most generated identifiers, making them effectively case insensitive in most dialects. Of course, you will run into issues when working with identifiers that conflict with reserved words...

Comment: I am using jooq 2.7.0 , I don't see setRenderQuotedNames method . I can see renderNameStyle ,renderKeywordStyle methods. Is it jooq version issue?

Comment: @Ramakrishna: There's no such version. The latest version of jOOQ 2.x was 2.6.4, which has been released 9 years ago... At the time, there was a [`Settings.renderNameStyle`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/2.6.x/org/jooq/conf/Settings.html#renderNameStyle) that mixed both quoting and identifier rendering behaviour.